# Amazon ASIN to Books ISBN

Tags: php, amazon-ecs

I am using [Amazon ECS PHP Library](https://github.com/Exeu/Amazon-ECS-PHP-Library/), I am looking up amazon books by ASIN and want to know the ISBN number. The return response includes everything except 10 digit ISBN number. Here is my script:

```
$response = $amazonEcs->responseGroup('Large')->lookup('B0099RKXE8');
```

How do I get book ISBN without scraping amazon site?

Comment: did you printed out the $response variable? `print_r($response);` ISBN is part of the ItemAttributes node and the Large response group should have it.

Comment: @juanreyesv Yes I did, it does not have ISBN

Comment: Have you tried your code for an item that actually has an ISBN?  Your sample item is a Kindle edition with no ISBN.

Comment: @DavidGorsline Yes I did, it does not show me ISBN

Answer (score 0):

Even responseGroup 'Medium' is enough if you just want to see ISBN.

Answer (score 0):

Your product is a kindle, books ASINs are ISBN 10, so if you find a product like this with 'B' in the begining, you can't find ISBN (ISBN13) in the results, to read more about difference about ISBN10 and ISBN13 : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Standard_Book_Number.